# What is snowflake database and Data warehouse - Can we do any ETL operations & reporting Operations in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is snowflake database and Data warehouse - Can we do any ETL operations & reporting Operations in Snowflake
Can we do ELT or ETL with snowflake subscription
Can we do any reporting with snowflake subscription
can we do any real time processing in Snowflake

Answer (score 0):

have a read and then come back with any specific questions:

[Snowflake](https://www.snowflake.com/)

[Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/index.html)